# Firestore authentication using Java SDK

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to modify the content of a firestore collection from a headless application using Java SDK. Write operations are currently allowed for a single user, who logs in using email and password(front-end).

Firestore Rule for front-end

[image: Firestore Rules]

I'm using the following json credentials file in my Java application.
[image: Json Credentials]

Currently getting a Permission Denied Exception. Which is understandable. What options do I have here to make headless Java Sdk application write to collection?

Comment: These rules don't apply for the server SDKs. You need to secure data using [IAM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/overview)

Comment: You're right, I missed this part of adding the service account to give permission. Right now setting the service account of above json key as "editor" gets the job done. What will be the correct role to enable only read/write access to firestore?

Comment: You can set it as "Datastore user"